# VBA Find Next Column start loop again

Tags: vba, excel

I know this will be an easy one but I just can't get it right after days of trying and googling so I didn't sound like an idiot asking here.

I am working on what should be a simple code to check values in columns named numeric are in fact numeric, counts the occurances and prints the cell.address.

There are numerous columns in numerous worksheets to search and the code works fine for the first column in all worksheets I just cant get the findNext code right so it loops through all Numeric columns before moving to the next worksheet.
(code includes the start for date value check for a second loop when I get numeric sorted out)

I would be sooooo greatful for any assitance so I dont lose any more hair. apologies in advance I am very new to VBA.

Code:

```
Sub ErrorFormatCount()

Dim j As Long
Dim LastRow, LastCol, DateCol, AssetCol, NumericCol As Long
Dim ErrorCount, Counter As Integer
Dim Toolwb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Toolwb = Workbooks("EDTDoctor")
    Toolwb.Sheets("Infrastructure").Activate
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ActiveSheet.Name = "EndSheetName" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        'On Error Resume Next
        NumericCol = ActiveSheet.Rows(7).Find("Numeric", Lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        DateCol = ActiveSheet.Rows(7).Find("Date", Lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        AssetCol = Rows(4).Find(What:="1035", Lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, AssetCol).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(AssetCol, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For j = 8 To LastRow
            ErrorCount = 0
            Counter = Toolwb.Sheets("Cover").Cells(41, "G").Value
            NextPrintCell = Toolwb.Sheets("Cover").Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

            If Not IsNumeric(Toolwb.ActiveSheet.Cells(j, NumericCol)) Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(j, NumericCol).Select
                Toolwb.Sheets("Cover").Cells(NextPrintCell, "G") _
                = ActiveCell.address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False, External:=True)
                ErrorCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveCell)
                Toolwb.Sheets("Cover").Cells(41, "G").Value = ErrorCount + Counter
            End If

         Next j

         Toolwb.ActiveSheet.Next.Activate
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Toolwb.Sheets("Cover").Activate
    MsgBox ("Checked For Formatting Errors" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
    & "Format  Errors Found" & " - " & Counter), vbInformation = vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

'Using Excel 2010

Comment: Think we need a bit more detail as to where the results should go.

Comment: No worries. The code loops through all rows in selected columns (columns in each ws with a header in row (7) "numeric" in most worksheets (except the first sheet "Cover" and last "EndSheetName". if is not numeric counts the occurance returns the cumulative result to cover!G41 and copies the cell address starting at Cover!G43 to next row for every numeric error found. Unfrortunately I am not able to change the worksheet workbook structure to make things easier as this  output is set by the clients data systems. Let me know if you need any more info or if you need a sample uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, still a few questions, which I have marked in comments. Let me know how you get on

```
Sub ErrorFormatCount()

Dim j As Long, k As Long
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, DateCol As Long, AssetCol As Long, NumericCol As Long
Dim ErrorCount As Long, Counter As Long
Dim Toolwb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Toolwb = Workbooks("EDTDoctor")

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "EndSheetName" Then
        Exit For
    End If
    'On Error Resume Next
    NumericCol = ws.Rows(7).Find(What:="Numeric", Lookat:=xlWhole).Column
    DateCol = ws.Rows(7).Find(What:="Date").Column
    AssetCol = ws.Rows(4).Find(What:="1035").Column
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, AssetCol).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = ws.Cells(AssetCol, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For j = 8 To LastRow
        For k = NumericCol To DateCol  'this is the loop for column but not sure if the start or end values are right
            Counter = Toolwb.Sheets("Cover").Cells(41, "G").Value
            NextPrintCell = Toolwb.Sheets("Cover").Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            If Not IsNumeric(ws.Cells(j, k)) Then
                Toolwb.Sheets("Cover").Cells(NextPrintCell, "G") _
                            = ws.Cells(j, k).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False, External:=True)
                ErrorCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Cells(j, k))
                Toolwb.Sheets("Cover").Cells(41, "G").Value = ErrorCount + Counter 'not sure if this should vary for different columns
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Toolwb.Sheets("Cover").Activate
MsgBox ("Checked For Formatting Errors" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
& "Format  Errors Found" & " - " & Counter), vbInformation = vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: @Mark Fitzgerald Thank you so much, I tweaked a little but works like a charm!

Comment: Not sure who is Mark Fitzgerald, but glad it worked. Perhaps you could mark it as an answer to your question?